# How nodes are distributed in decentralized blockchain networks

Tags: nodes, blockchain, peer

I'm trying to build a blockchain using the programming and infrastructure, thus all I'm confused is How nodes are distributed in decentralized blockchain networks.

Comment: Could you provide more information. Which blockchain technology are you using?
For example: Ethereum is using so called "bootnodes" to connect the running nodes with each other

Comment: I have two options to go with one on Ethereum and other on Hyperledger Fabric, since I'm unable to understand the distribution of nodes in decentralized blockchain networks, thus i'm at fix. So I request you to please explain both in case of Ethereum and Hyperledger fabric

Comment: Your question does not have enough detail to offer a good answer but there are a few starter projects on Github on how to start building a blockchain network...I'd start there.

Comment: Hello Rey, to be precise i wanted to know How nodes are distributed & communicate in decentralized blockchain networks. In Ethereum and Hyperledger Fabric?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer for the ethereum blockchain.

There you have so called "bootnodes". Their only task is to welcome new nodes and let them meet the other nodes on the network. These bootnodes have a static IP address and a list of all nodes running in the network.
When you start a new node it can ask a bootnode for all the nodes in the network, to become a new member of the blockchain network.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question I assume that you do not have a clear understanding of the concepts of blockchain.

The distribution, or to phrase it correctly, the participating criteria for any node in the blockchain is dependant on its architecture.

In public blockchain's like bitcoin or ethereum, any individual can become a node and start participating in the network. There is no oversight over who can join, or how many nodes can you create. All your transactions are recorded on the main-net and visible to everyone.

However, in private blockchain's like hyperledger fabric for example, there is specific criteria dictated by the channel organisations on who can join and which peers can process the block. This makes it suitable for use cases involving a set number of organisations trading/communicating with one another, and wishing to have a shared ledger that is privy to them.